# What is the most efficient method for producing dots in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm generating identical dots using two different composable approaches, and I'm interested in determining which one is both more straightforward to use and more efficient in Jetpack Compose.

```
  //1st code
    
  Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    for (i in 0..3) {
        PinIndicator(
            filled = when (i) {
                0 -> numbers.isNotEmpty()
                else -> numbers.size > i
            }
        )
    }

}
 
 //2nd code here

Row(
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
) {
    PinIndicator(filled = numbers.isNotEmpty())
    PinIndicator(filled = numbers.size > 1)
    PinIndicator(filled = numbers.size > 2)
    PinIndicator(filled = numbers.size > 3)
}
```

Both are creating the above Preview-

[image]

dots composable -

```
@Composable
private fun PinIndicator(
    filled: Boolean,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(15.dp)
            .size(15.dp)
            .clip(CircleShape)
            .background(if (filled) Color.Black else Color.Transparent)
            .border(2.dp, Color.Black, CircleShape)
    )
}
```

Comment: I guess the first one is more better

Comment: Efficiency is the same, first one is more straightforward. Moreover `numbers.isNotEmpty()` is the same as `numbers.size > 0`, so you don't need the when at all, you can do just `filled = numbers.size > i`.

Comment: And you can also replace `for (i in 0..3) {}` with `repeat(4) {}`, which makes it more obvious how many items you are showing...

Comment: @JanBína you are correct I removed the when the block (I put that because it was crashing somewhere now I fixed it) Thanks,

Comment: As @JanBína mention the first approach is  better just change for with repeat and just as an advice even if the second approach would be faster or more efficient it will not make sense to use in a production app because the code is not readable like the first one